# Javascript Object Property Inheritence

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

My goal with my method is to inherit the property name 'c' and append it to obj1. Not sure what I am missing here, instead of 'c' my meth inherits the name 'key2'.

```js
var obj1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
};
var obj2 = {
  b: 4,
  c: 3
};

function extend(obj1, obj2) {
    output = {};
    for(var key in obj1){
        for(var key2 in obj2){
            if(key !== key2){
               obj1.key2= obj2[key2];
            }
        }
    }
    return obj1;

    
}
extend(obj1, obj2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are hard coding the Property name `key2`. It needs to be assigned like `obj1[key2]`. Javascript allows you to add property dynamically and the property name can be determined at runtime too. So, `Obj1[key2]` creates the dynamic properties.

Also, note that since you are using the `in` operator and no additional check is done for property using `Object.hasOwnProperty()` method. In case of objects with Prototype chain, you can get different results which you sometime might not be desirable.

```js
var obj1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
};
var obj2 = {
  b: 4,
  c: 3
};

function extend(obj1, obj2) {
    output = {};
    for(var key in obj1){
        for(var key2 in obj2){
            if(key !== key2){
               obj1[key2]= obj2[key2];
            }
        }
    }
    return obj1;

    
}
console.log(extend(obj1, obj2));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write `obj1.key2` you're setting a property called `key2`.

That's just how JS property shorthand notation works.

You want `obj1[key2]`.

You're also returning `obj1`; not sure what `output` is for.

Answer (score 0):

On line `15` you are assigning the property on `obj1` to `.key2` instead you should assign the property like so `obj1[key2]`. This will do an assignment with the key value, just like when you do key lookups.

There is also the curious case of the `output` variable being unused and not defined, in my example I have removed it from the code.

Fixed example:

```js
var obj1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
};
var obj2 = {
  b: 4,
  c: 3
};

function extend(obj1, obj2) {
    for(var key in obj1){
        for(var key2 in obj2){
            if(key !== key2){
               obj1[key2] = obj2[key2];
            }
        }
    }
    return obj1;

    
}
extend(obj1, obj2)

console.log(obj1)
```